# Generating an HTML color code for event category in ai1ec

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, all-in-one-event-calendar

*Although this question relates to a particular Wordpress plugin called the All in One Event Calender by Time.ly it can also be a general PHP related question.*

I am trying to modify a theme to use event colours selected in the ai1ec back end and would like to produce a simple HTML colour code - ie "#f2f2f2"

The plugin itself has loads of functions and php shortcodes to pull a wealth of information off each event such as the one listed below.

`<?php echo $event->get_category_text_color(); ?>` which will print `style="color: #f2a011;"`

Can also change to print `style="background-color: #f2a011;"` with the use of `$event->get_category_bg_color();`

**Now the real meat of the question**

All I want to do is get that HTML colour so I can also code it into buttons and other visual elements. I have scoured through blogs and code to try and find something that does it to no avail.

What I was wondering is if you could **write a filter of some sort to just take the information within the `"#f2f2f2"` quotation marks.** I know it's not called a filter as searches for php filter return information about something completely different - I'm a self taught PHP programmer and so searching for a lot of terms I don't know can be pretty tough!

Comment: I'm not getting it. You just want to get the #something from the string "color: #f2a011;"?

Comment: Check this search results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+hex+color+string

Comment: if you want so, you can do that using a quite simple explode or a regex. I'm not a regex master, but this will quite do the job: `$matches = array(); preg_match('/?=#(.*(?=;)))/', $event->get_category_text_color(), $matches);`. This will match "f2a011" in the above case. Also, you may simply use substr(), if the string is constant

Comment: Hi yes @briosheje , for some reason there is no way to simply grab the colour off it so the closest I can find to getting the category colour is through that string. The beginning of the string is always constant but if for example `"#FFF"` was called I think I'd find errors. When I echo `$matches` above however I get array"

Comment: @Bysander: the above case works also with "#fff", as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/3vp5v8 . Please echo $matches[0], not $matches, else you will print the array, not the value of the array. if you want to print the array, use print_r($matches); .

Comment: oh ok! amazing thank you @briosheje. If you post it as an answer I'm very happy to accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed above, substr would be a great solution but it wouldn't solve the case where the color code is expressed in this format:

```
#FFF;
```

instead of:

```
#FFFFFF;
```

Therefore, this regex should do the job quite well:

> '/?=#(.*(?=;)))/'

Example:

[image: proof]

```
$matches = array();
preg_match('/?=#(.*(?=;)))/', $event->get_category_text_color(), $matches);
$colorCode = "#{$matches[0]};";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `substr()` function like so:

```
echo substr($event->get_category_text_color(),14,-2);
```

Which in the example, would return `#f2f2f2`.